# Second partial derivative test for multivariable function R^n to R^n

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can we make Hessian matrix for function $f:\Bbb R^n \mapsto \Bbb R^n$? If we can, then Hessian matrix has its component as a vector. But it seems not well-defined for me. Could anyone explain how to apply second derivative test in this case?

Comment: is this in relation to finding a minumum or maximum?

Comment: @ellya Yes, and I just realized that my question is bad question, since we cannot define order of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my next comment :)

Comment: The question is not so bad as it seems at the first sight: it would interest me, if the Jacobi matrix is singular, whether we can derive from higher order derivatives the [topological degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) of the map at some neighborhood of a zero point (i.e. how many times and in which direction it goes around $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arrange the second-order partials of $\mathbf f$ into a matrix $\mathbf H$, although it is not going to be an actual matrix, due to vector-valued entries. It's just a way of organizing the partials: 
$$\mathbf H_{ij} = \frac{\partial ^2 \mathbf f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
For consistency, we can also organize the first-order derivatives similarly:
$$\mathbf D_{i } = \frac{\partial   \mathbf f}{\partial x_i  }$$
Then the Taylor expansion of second order looks neat:
$$
\mathbf f(\mathbf x+\mathbf v) = \mathbf f(\mathbf x) + \sum_{i=1}^n 
\mathbf D_{i } v_i + \frac12\sum_{i,j=1}^n \mathbf H_{ij }  v_iv_j +o(\|\mathbf v\|^2)
$$
But sooner or later the indices start getting in the way, especially if there is more than one coordinate system to consider. The language of [tensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) allows us to manipulate objects like $\mathbf H$ without stopping down every time to name indices and indicate their ranges. It is natural to think of $\mathbf H$ as a $(1,2)$-tensor, meaning that it's a device that takes two vectors and produces one vector.